# PostgresSQL Alter column giving invalid input syntax for type date: ""

Tags: postgresql

I'm not super experienced at this, but I have a column which now houses stings which need to be altered to dates. It's giving me an error for when there are only empty strings. Here's what's up.

```
ALTER TABLE artist
ALTER COLUMN available_from TYPE date USING available_from::date;
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
invalid input syntax for type date: ""
```

Then I tried

```
ALTER TABLE artist
ALTER COLUMN available_from TYPE date USING (NULLIF(available_from),'')::date,
```

Which gave me:

```
syntax error at or near ")"
```

Anyone who can help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplaced the `)` in the second statement:

```
ALTER TABLE artist
   ALTER COLUMN available_from TYPE date 
   USING (NULLIF(available_from,''))::date,
                                   ^ 
                                   | here
```

Comment: How do you compare a column of type date with a string? I get this error "SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "".

Comment: It only works on my end using 'null' to compare values "ALTER TABLE artist  ALTER COLUMN available_from TYPE date  USING (NULLIF(available_from, null))::date"

Comment: @DavidDonari: if you have a new question, then please ask a new question. But `NULLIF(available_from, null)::date` makes no sense. `nullif()` returns a null value if the first value is equal to the second. Your expression essentially the same as `available_from::date`